# Download and Extract Zip file

Tags: python

I want  to download a zip file from an url but i don't want to save it temporarily because, the only way i know to download and extract a zip file to somewhere is to create an empty zipfile where will be paste the downloaded zip content and then, extract that in the correct folder. But i want to download and extract without having to create a zip folder. I tried a bunch of things but none of these works. Does someone know how to do that ?
(my code is maybe bad, i don't know but i don't really care that much)

```py
import io
import zipfile
import requests
import json
import os

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://beatsaver.com'
page = 0
num = 0
req = requests.get(url + '/api/maps/latest/' + str(page), headers=headers)
latest = json.loads(req.text)
for item in latest['docs']:
    print(latest['docs'][num]['downloadURL'])
    dl = requests.get(url + latest['docs'][num]['directDownload'])
    path = './maps/{} - {} - {}'.format(latest['docs'][num]['key'], latest['docs'][num]['name'].replace(':', '').replace('?', ''), latest['docs'][num]['uploader']['username'])
    os.mkdir(path)
    #here is where i want it to download the zip
    num += 1
```

Comment: "I don't want to save it temporarily"..what does it mean? What is the error..if any? Can you clarify a little?

Comment: I hope you will understand now, sorry if there is/are some mistakes, i'm french

Comment: Where do you want them extracted to? Can you give me an example path on your system?

Comment: In this case, i want the content of /api/maps/11fff in the file F:\Python\DailyDownloader\maps\`the name of the file`. In this case, the file contains some json files and a song

Comment: I know. You are scraping the download links from the json. I downloaded one to check it. The file name(folder name..after extraction) is something like this..`8be3144789fb89834402a7ec2e0dd4e8844144b3.zip` ..That's what you want?

Comment: here's what i'm talking about, i've made a programm before that was doing somthing similar [here](https://pastebin.com/msSEacNS). Here, i write the request content in `temp.zip` and then extract it, but i don't want to use `temp.zip` and want to directly extract content in the located in /playlistpath/songname

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could not add this as a comment because of the code. However, I think you mean this.It is not using `requests` though.

> Now this method will not create and save any files. It will directly
> save the extracted file.

```
    from io import BytesIO
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    zipurl = 'http://stash.compjour.org/data/1800ssa.zip'
    with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
        with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
            zfile.extractall('/tmp/mystuff4')
```

Reference:- https://svaderia.github.io/articles/downloading-and-unzipping-a-zipfile/

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea but it's not i was talking about (but thanks anyway)

Comment: @Moréo then you should explain why it's not what you're talking about, and also explain what you're talking about more clearly, so we don't keep wasting our time

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exaclty what i need. I'm sorry about taking your time. Thanks a lot